# Features protobuf performance

Tags: tensorflow

I'm playing with MNIST examples and noticed that protobuf serialized features are horribly slow both serialize and deserialize.

My simple test reads CSV with 42000 images and writes it into binary file using TFRecordWriter. Benchmark results are quite surprising:

- pickle of image as string: 19.292 seconds, size=130MB
- Example/Features encoding, byte array: 108.510 seconds, size=100MB
- Example/Features encoding, int64 array: 145.014 seconds, size=39MB

With quite plausible size results, looks like protobuf feature encoding is very slow. I see the same slow results on reading, Example.FromString() is ~5-7 times slower than pickle.

Are there tricks/suggestions how to overcome this?

My encoding code snippet is below.

```
    writer = TFRecordWriter(FLAGS.out)
        image_id = 1
        for row in reader:
            row = map(int, row)
            f_dict = {}
            label = row[0]
            image = row[1:]
            f_dict["label"] = tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64ListList(value=[label]))
            f_dict["image"] = tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64ListList(value=image))

            features = tf.train.Features(feature=f_dict)
            example = tf.train.Example(features=features)
            writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
```

Comment: Not sure.. I don't see any mention of buffering .. So are you hitting 42K separate serialization calls then sequential writes and flushes  ?  I know in general serializing individual records is slow and you normally serialize arrays of records.  In this case your also hitting the python / C++ transition cost which has to copy or pin data on each record.

Comment: Could you set the following environment variables and see if it's still slow? PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=cpp
PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION_VERSION=2

Comment: I'm encountering a similar problem. Did you find any way of increasing the speed of TFRecordWriter? Thanks!